# Temporarily attach/connect to SQL Server LocalDB file

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, localdb

I am trying to programmatically create and connect to an application specific LocalDB database. I would like to do this by specifying the file name of a `.MDF` file only, ideally without specifying an instance name or a name for the database that gets registered anywhere.

The database is to be accessed from some unit tests so it will only be used for a brief time before being deleted. My current approach creates the `.MDF` file correctly but also registers the name with the default instance which I would like to avoid given the temporary and 'non-singleton' nature of the database instances.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do, or have I misunderstood how LocalDB works?

Answer (score 4):

[LocalDB automatic instance with specific data file](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance-with-specific-data-file/)

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;
```

*Update*

This can be used with the Deployment area in your .testsettings file. You just need to check 'Enable deployment' and add both the .mdf and .ldf files to 'Additional files and directories to deploy'.

You can then simply use the connection string above, and the test runner will take care of moving your data files to an appropriate temp folder for you.

Answer (score 0):

Chrisb's answer got me on the right lines to solve this, but I noticed that the database remained attached to the default instance in LocalDB even after the connection had been closed. I read that this might eventually be purged after a few minutes but in my case this was too long as the file was located in a temporary directory used by MSTest and had to be closed in time for the cleanup at the end of the test run.

The solution was to use a connection string similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26712648 and a detach process similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646319 immediately after I had finished using the connection.

Creating the MDF file in the first place could be accomplished by connecting to the automatic LocalDB instance, executing CREATE DATABASE and then using the same detach method. By using the file name for the database name, which is allowed in LocalDB due to the much longer names permitted, I ensured beyond reasonable doubt that the database name will not clash with anything else on the computer even during the short period it stays attached.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a missed assumption - using .testsettings files and Deployment means you don't need to worry about detach and so on...  You have a master .mdf/.ldf sitting in a resources folder, and the test engine handles copying it around when your unit tests execute.

Comment: I am working in VSCode. `sp_detach_db` mentioned in your link did not work for me. The universal way seem to be psexec `sqllocaldb.exe stop <db_to_release_mdf_now>`